# Email icon (messaging menu) in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: icons, email, notification, messaging-menu, mail-notification

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed and Mailnag to check my Gmail account.

With Ubuntu 14.10 I had a email icon (messaging menu, provided by indicator-messages package, that I currently have installed) that becomes blue with new email notificacionts and showed a unread counter (if I click in the email icon).

With ubuntu 16.04 I haven't this icon, but I have indicator-messages installed. ¿How can I recover the icon (o some equivalent) that indicates if I have unread emails? Mailnag is working, it shows the new email popup, but when the pop up disssapears I have no visual indication

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the problem is that ubuntu doesn't have mailnag-unity-plugin.

I installed from his ppa and its working.